# Kubernetes Error: unknown flag: --export error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

[image][unknown flag: --export while copying secret from one namespace to another kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481963/unknown-flag-export-while-copying-secret-from-one-namespace-to-another-kubect)

I solved my problem with the above solution but i dont know why i got this error.

Above answers says on kubernetes 1.14 export option deprecated and on 1.18 it has been remove but i use 1.16.

Secondly on GCP my cluster started to give warning at the same time.

Why i get this error while i should not? Am i looking wrong direction?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-regular#October_02_2020), [current versions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#current_versions). Looks like you're using outdated GKE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Kubernetes 1.14, --export is deprecated and this feature is removed in 1.18. You can use get -o yaml without --export. For example, the following command export secrets config:

```
kubectl get secret <your secrets> --namespace <your namespace> -o yaml > output.yaml
```